# How to split date ranges based on months in C#.net using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

I would like to split the date range into the respective months.
For example, I've a data in the following way:

```
startdate   enddate
2013-04-04  2014-01-31
```

I want to be able to display the above data in this way:

```
 startdate   enddate     
 2013-04-04  2013-04-30
 2013-05-01  2013-06-30  --(2 month difference)
 2013-07-01  2013-08-31
 2013-09-01  2013-10-31
 2013-11-01  2013-12-31
 2014-01-01  2014-01-31
```

Can somebody help me with using `List` and recursion?

A sample code that tried without recursion

```
          List<DateInformation> lDateCol1 = new List<DateInformation>();
          List<DateInformation> lDateCol = new List<DateInformation>();
          lResult.DateFrom = '4/4/2013';
          lResult.DateUntil = '31/01/2014';


        DateTime Today;
        DateTime FirstDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        DateTime LastDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime NextFirstDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        DateTime NextLastDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime InputStartDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        DateTime InputEndDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        Today = lResult.DateFrom;
        FirstDate = new DateTime(Today.Year, 1, 1);
          int monthsApart = Math.Abs(12 * (lResult.DateFrom.Year - lResult.DateUntil.Year) + lResult.DateFrom.Month - lResult.DateUntil.Month)


        for (int daycount = 0; daycount < 12; daycount += noofmonths)
        {
          if (count == 0)
          {
            NextLastDate = FirstDate.AddMonths(noofmonths).AddDays(-1);
            lDateCol1.Add(new DateInformation(FirstDate, NextLastDate));
          }
          if (count > 0)
          {
            NextFirstDate = NextLastDate.AddDays(1);
            NextLastDate = new DateTime(NextFirstDate.Year, NextFirstDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(noofmonths).AddDays(-1);
            lDateCol1.Add(new DateInformation(NextFirstDate, NextLastDate));
          }
          count = count + 1;
        }
        for (count = 0; count <= lDateCol1.Count - 1; count++)
        {
          if ((lDateCol1[count].DateFrom <= lResult.DateFrom) && (lResult.DateFrom <= (lDateCol1[count].DateUntil)))
          {
            InputStartDate = lResult.DateFrom;
            InputEndDate = lDateCol1[count].DateUntil;
            NextFirstDate = InputStartDate;
            NextLastDate = InputEndDate;
            lDateCol.Add(new DateInformation(NextFirstDate, NextLastDate));
            break;
          }
        }

        for (int daycount = 0; daycount <= monthsApart; daycount += noofmonths)
        {
          NextFirstDate = NextLastDate.AddDays(1);
          NextLastDate = new DateTime(NextFirstDate.Year, NextFirstDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(noofmonths).AddDays(-1);
          if (!(NextLastDate < lResult.DateUntil))
          {
            lDateCol.Add(new DateInformation(NextFirstDate, lResult.DateUntil));
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            lDateCol.Add(new DateInformation(NextFirstDate, NextLastDate));
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Why do you need recursion?

Comment: What does recursion have to do with this? Homework requiring it? Have you *tried anything* on your own yet?

Comment: Just outputting a list of start and end dates isn't recursion, it's just a loop.  And unless you want to store the start and end dates, a list isn't necessary either.  Also, you'd need to specify when a 2 month difference is required and when a 1 month difference is required to get a complete answer to how to calculate the dates you need.

Comment: There are different ways to do it, was it in SQL or C#... none of it uses recursion...

Comment: And what did you use to store these dates? File, database or just arrays?

Comment: So are you wanting to display the dates in a `Grid like `View` or are you wanting to display the dates in a `Sorted View`? `List<T>` is a `Generic Collection Object` where as `Recursion` is calling the Same `Method` over again until a particular condition has been met; for example. You are getting Objects and Methods confused here

Comment: You'd be better off using `DateTime`s and `TimeSpan`s rather than `List`s or a recursion.

Comment: A sample code that I have tried without recursion is

Comment: @febin edit your question to add that code. Don't try to put it in the comments

Comment: @febin You should edit your question to accomodate your sample code, instead of trying to write it as a comment.

Comment: what's the status of this question? If you solved it, close this

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it the hard way with your sample. There's a much easier way to find the start and end of months:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
DateTime monthStart = d.AddDays(-(d.Day - 1));
DateTime monthEnd = monthStart.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

You don't really need recursion to do this, btw, but if it's part of an assignment to use recursion then simply create a function that takes start and end dates. Use the method above to find the month start and end, do what you will with them then pass the first day of the next month (aka `monthEnd.AddDays(1)` ) back into the function as the start date along with the original end date. *Voilà!* Recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Just did some quick non-recursive code

```
DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse("2013-04-04");
DateTime enddate = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-31");
DateTime parseDate;
List<DateTime> startings = new List<DateTime>();
List<DateTime> endings = new List<DateTime>();
startings.Add(startdate);
parseDate = startdate.AddMonths(1);
while(parseDate.Day != 1)
    parseDate=parseDate.AddDays(-1);
parseDate=parseDate.AddDays(-1);
endings.Add(parseDate);
while (parseDate<enddate)
{
    parseDate = parseDate.AddDays(1);
    startings.Add(parseDate);
    parseDate = parseDate.AddMonths(2);
    parseDate = parseDate.AddDays(-1);
    endings.Add(parseDate);
}
endings[endings.Count() - 1] = enddate;
```

This saves 2 lists: `startings` and `endings`

```
[0] {04-04-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[1] {01-05-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[2] {01-07-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[3] {01-09-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[4] {01-11-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[5] {01-01-2014 00:00:00}   System.DateTime

[0] {30-04-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[1] {30-06-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[2] {31-08-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[3] {31-10-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[4] {31-12-2013 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
[5] {31-01-2014 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
```

As you can see some quick dirty code with less than 20 lines of code can achieve those values